# SwiftUI: How to hide List scroll bar?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple `List`. I would like to hide the vertical scrollbar on the right. Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of showing indicator for all `Lists`, but with an API of the `UITableView`. because SwiftUI `List` is using `UITableView` for iOS behind the scene:

```
init() {
   UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}
```